# how to do HTML google multilevel entry?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, web

I wanted to ask a maybe dumb question but how do you guys set up an html website to look like this when searched on google?

Ive tried adding anchor tags to the meta tags, yes maybe quite dumb idea , well it didn't work, does anybody know how to? Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generated automatcally by Google, but you can help the robots to show the right things using a sitemap: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184 also it allows you to make a link preview.

PS: There is lots of tools to do that, like this one https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Answer (score 4):

With Sitelinks

As Google Webmaster Tools explains:

> Sitelinks are automatically generated links that may appear under your
>   site's search results

This means you can't add them via some tool or code. The best you can do is to structure your correctly. See Google's page about this https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334&hl=en